# How do you initiate/force a download for files that reside externally in PHP or other language?

Tags: java, php, html, http-headers

If you have images or other files that reside externally, how do force the browser to download the link when a user click on it?

The use of "Content-disposition: attachment;" header would do that, but it is not working for files that resides externally without reading and importing the file locally.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to load the resource on the server first. You might want to do some caching also:

```
<?php
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.jpg");
  echo file_get_contents("http://host.tld/path/to/myfile.jpg");
?>
```

Comment: But file_get_contents() will read the file to the local server which is what I try to avoid.

Comment: Only temporarily in memory or temp disk. It's however your best bet. There are really no other ways. You *have* to act as proxy whenever you'd like to change the response headers of an external resource.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You cannot dictate a client how to handle a different resource than the currently requested one.

You could only use a proxy to fetch the external external file and pass it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to force a file download if you are not controlling the HTTP headers.  `Content-disposition: attachment` is the only way I know of to accomplish this.

Though this is probably not going to work, my only guess would be trying to combine `Content-disposition` with a `Location` header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.jpg
Location: http://www.somesite.com/myfile.jpg
```

(it's a long shot, probably invalid and/or just bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of the aforementioned "Content-Disposition" header, as well as forcing the type:

```
header("Content-type: attachment/octet-stream");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a method similar to this for downloading mp4 files, could work for text files:

```
$file=fopen('http://example.com/example.txt','r');
header("Content-Type:text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.txt");
fpassthru($file);
```

Comment: does this first downloads the file to the server or directly provides it to the user

Comment: it actually download the file to ur ram first so it will be affecting the speed of your server a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the download attribute. Just add download = 'filename.extension' to the download link:

```
 <a link='mysite.com/sfsf.extension' download='filenameuwant.extension'></a>
```