# PHP (or Flash) file download - set headers then redirect

Tags: php, flash

I would like to do this, without the "readfile()" part:

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file)); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename="".basename($file)."""); 
readfile("$file");
```

Basically I am trying to forward a download to another URL but at the same time I need to be able to set headers like "filename".

The readfile($file) function will not do it for me, because the the $file is not stored on the same server as the PHP script (not even the same datacenter)

Is this even possible ? If not via PHP, maybe FLASH could do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do so with PHP is for PHP to first download the file from the remote server, and then send it to the user. You can actually use `readfile` for this, as it supports fopen wrappers, as long as the option is enabled on your server.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did not want to to this, because the files we are talking about could be 1GB in size.. I need to save bandwith.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wish to get the file to download in this way via PHP you can use

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.jpg");
  echo file_get_contents("http://host.tld/path/to/myfile.jpg")
```

Quoted from Byron Whitlock on another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449331/how-do-you-initiate-force-a-download-for-files-that-reside-externally-in-php-or-o).
He explains that this code will put the file in temporary storage, so the download and deletion of the original file will be dealt with automatically.

If you don't have to use PHP, you could use a hidden iFrame on the page to download the file

Comment: If I use file_get_contents , the server will have to first download the 1GB file from the original destination, then push it to client. Bandwith combined = 2 GB - that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: If I use iframe, I will not be able to change the filename of the downloading file.

Comment: Even if you did want to download it from the remote server, file_get_contents would be bad. It buffers the whole file in memory before outputting it to the user. You should use `readfile` in such case which streams the file without buffering it in memory in whole.